# How to write a retroactive letter of representation?

Tags: united-states, new-york-state, signature, legal-representation

An attorney began representation of Mr. X some months ago, as assigned counsel, without a letter of representation.  Such a letter is needed now in order to make a court-ordered restitution payment to a certain company (which requires a signed letter of representation).

1. Should this letter be back-dated, or
2. should it be written in the past tense, stating the date that representation began?
3. Or should it be a regular letter, with the current date (I'm thinking that for the purposes of the restitution payment, maybe the only thing that matters is the fact that Mr. X is currently represented.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since Mr X has a lawyer, the lawyer should advise what form this letter should take to be most helpful to Mr X's interests.

In the absence of such advice, I would suggest soemthing like

> My lawyer, Y, now represents me in connection with {matter} and has done so since {date}.

Plus any additional content that the company wants to see.

Comment: Thank you, David.  So, not back-dated.  Very helpful.